# Efficient multiple, arbitrary index access in Python tuple?

Tags: python, tuples, slice

I have a long Python tuple `t`.  I would like to grab the elements at indices `i1`, `i2`, ..., `iN` from `t` as efficiently as possible.  What's the best way?

One approach is:

```
(1)    result = [t[j] for j in (i1, i2, ..., iN)]
```

but this would seem to cause N separate lookups into the tuple.  Is there a faster way?  When Python does slices like this:

```
(2)    result = t[1:M:3]
```

I assume that it does not perform M/3 separate lookups.  (Maybe it uses a bitmask and does a single copy operation?)  Is there some way for me to capitalize on whatever Python does in (2) to make my arbitrary-index slice happen in a single copy?

Thanks.

Comment: Indexing instances of builtin sequence types is among the fastest things you can do. The only reason slicing on those is slightly more efficient than doing it yourself in a loop is because it's written in C and looping as well as (even implicitly) calling methods has a larger overhead in Python. Plus, tricks that apply to slicing (if there are such tricks... you have to copy each item either way) is only possible at all if `i1` through `iN` are multiples of the same number plus some constant.

Comment: How are you determining (i1... iN)? Maybe there are gains to be made in efficiency (and simplicity), but only by rewriting at a wider scope...

Comment: This is an interesting and surprising optimization to me. Can you post a link to the code, the performance test, and the cProfile results for us to check out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are doing a bunch of identical lookups, it may be worth using an itemgetter

```
from operator import itemgetter
mygetter = itemgetter(i1, i2, ..., iN)
for tup in lots_of_tuples:
    result = mygetter(tup)
```

For one off, the overhead of creating the itemgetter is not worthwhile

Quick test in iPython shows:

```
In [1]: import random

In [2]: from operator import itemgetter

In [3]: t=tuple(range(1000))

In [4]: idxs = tuple(random.randrange(1000) for i in range(20))

In [5]: timeit [t[i] for i in idxs]
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.09 us per loop

In [6]: mygetter = itemgetter(*idxs)

In [7]: timeit mygetter(t)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 596 ns per loop
```

Obviously the difference will depend on the length of the tuple, the number of indices, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and the performance example.  I was not aware of itemgetter, and it precisely answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

The one you've listed is the most optimal way to get the elements from a tuple. You usually don't care about the performance in such expressions – it's a premature optimisation, and even if you did, such operations are already too slow even with the optimisations, i.e. if you optimise the access the loop itself will still be slow due to reference counting of the temporary variables and etc.

If you already have a performance issue or this is already part of CPU-heavy code you can try several alternatives:

1) `numpy` arrays:

```
>>> arr = np.array(xrange(2000))
>>> mask = np.array([True]*2000)
>>> mask = np.array([False]*2000)
>>> mask[3] = True
>>> mask[300] = True
>>> arr[mask]
array([  3, 300])
```

2) You can use the C API to copy the elements using `PyTuple_GET_ITEM` which accesses the internal array directly, but be warned that using the C API is not trivial and can introduce a lot of bugs.

3) You can use C arrays with the C API, using e.g. the buffer interface of `array.array` to glue the data access to Python.

4) You can use Cython with C arrays and a custom Cython type for data access from Python.

5) You can use Cython and `numpy` together.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the list comprehension there is an implicit `for` loop, and I am pretty sure it is iterating through the tuple values with reasonable efficiency.  I don't think you can improve on the list comprehension for efficiency.

If you just need the values you might be able to use a generator expression and avoid building the list, for a slight savings in time or memory.

Answer (score 0):

Slicing *can* be more efficient because it has more constraints: the index must proceed in a linear fashion by a fixed amount. The list comprehension could be completely random so no optimization is possible.

Still it's dangerous to make assumptions about efficiency. Try timing both ways and see if there's a significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

1) Are you sure you need the operation to go faster?

2) Another option is `operator.itemgetter`: It returns a tuple picked by its indexes:

```
>>> t = tuple(string.ascii_uppercase)
>>> operator.itemgetter(13,19,4,21,1)(t)
('N', 'T', 'E', 'V', 'B')
```

The `operator` module is implemented in C, so will likely outperform a Python loop.